# How create and add relation to two entities at same time

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, backend, typeorm

I am have two entites, Coupon and discount, each coupon can have many discounts,and each discount can have only one discount. I need two create new discount and coupon from one request,request body look like this

```
 "title": "someTitle",
  "description": "someDesc",
  "deadline": "someDeadline",
  "image": "someImg",
  "rules": "someRules",
  "company":"15",
  "category":"1",
  "discounts": [
    {
      "discount":"ad",
      "price":"awd"
    }
]
```

after this request, I need create new discount from provided array discounts,create new coupon ,and connect it
[coupon.entity.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEmTy.png)
[discount.entity.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdNUT.png)

[coupon.service.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAUcd.png)

after this I am getting error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgp33.png)

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Include all relevant code and error messages as text in your questions/answers when on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please spend a few minutes to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Also review [ask] and [why should i not upload images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).  Finally see the documentation for [Transactions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by creating the discount first, and then adding it to the coupon entity. You can do this using an API route by first getting the discount data from the request, then making a new discount entity from it like so:

````
createDiscount(req, res, { table: 'discount' }).then(async discountData => { const couponData = await createCoupon(req, res, { table: 'coupon', discountId: discountData.id }); return couponData; });```
````

Answer (score 0):

One tip I could give is to try and look up on how to create a transaction where you create first the discount lines, then you create the coupon with the discounts created.
Finnaly you commit the transaction.